# Question regarding complex numbers and real numbers?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, real-numbers

I have two questions...
If we take $(-1/3)^{(-1/3)}$ it would equal $-1.44224957$ since...
$$(-1/3)^{-1/3}$$
$$\frac{1}{(-1/3)^{(1/3)}}$$
$$\frac{1}{-0.6933612744}$$
$$-1.44224957\ldots$$

Yet when I place my calculator as $$e^{\left(-\frac{1}{3}\right)\ln\left(-\frac{1}{3}\right)}$$

I would get the complex number of $$.721124785-1.124902477i$$
So does $.721124785-1.124902477i=-1.44224957$?

As I continued with this I found that for negative $x$-values $x^x=(-x)^x$ for $x$ values with $-\frac{\text{even numerators}}{\text{odd denominators}}$ and $-(-x)^{(x)}$ for x values for $-\frac{\text{odd numerator}}{\text{odd denominators}}$ so....

$$(-x)^x=e^{x\ln(-x)}$$
$$-(-x)^x=-e^{x\ln(-x)}$$

For the both of them...

$$\ln{\left((-x)^{x}\right)}=x\ln(-x)$$
Then dividing by $x$
$$\ln(-x)=\ln(-x)$$

So does $\ln(x)=\ln(-x)$ when the $x$-value is $-\frac{\text{even/odd number}}{\text{odd number}}$?

Comment: Branch cuts, if you respect them they lift you up. If you abuse them, they'll snap and send you flying down a cliff.

Comment: No, your real value doesn't equal the complex value.  _However_, they are (assuming you did everything correctly) both solutions.  You have to remember that when you have $x^\frac{a}{b}$ that you will get $b$ complex solutions (assuming $\frac{a}{b}$ is reduced fully).

Comment: Again some pseudo-paradoxes based on the well known fact that $z^w$ does not have a meaning for every $z$ and $w$ in the complex plane.

Comment: And hopefully it's clear by the way that I wrote my above comment that $a$ and $b$ _must_ be integers...if you have $x^r$ and $r$ is irrational then there are an _infinite_ number of roots.  It's always fun to check that $i$ really is an irrational number by showing that $1^i$ has infinite roots.

Comment: Sorry, didn't know much about use of branch cuts. Well now I know :).

Comment: Hey @Did, you must have known about this when you were young but I am not that kind of person.

Comment: @Arbuja It seems you are not the kind of person who searches for similar questions already asked, either.

Comment: I have searched other questions and none of them were specifically about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will never be true that $\ln(-x) = \ln(x)$ because the logarithm of a negative must always be complex.  It's $\require{cancel} \cancel{\text{possible}}$ that there are complex solutions of $\text{Log}(x)$ that equal *a* complex solution of $\text{Log}(-x)$.

I think it's easiest to solve this in the context of general complex numbers, i.e. $re^{\theta i}$.  Now we have the following:

$$
\text{Log}\left(re^{\theta i}\right) = y \rightarrow e^y = re^{\theta i + 2\pi ni}
$$

We can safely rewrite $r = e^{\ln(r)}$ since $r$ is a *positive* real number which gives:

$$
e^y = e^{\ln(r) + \theta i + 2\pi ni}
$$

Finally we see that $\text{Log}(re^{\theta i}) = \ln(r) + (\theta + 2\pi n)i$.  When $x$ is a real positive value we get $r = x$ and $\theta = 0$:

$$
\text{Log}(x) = \ln(x) + 2\pi ni
$$

When $x$ is negative we get $r = x$ and $\theta = \pi$:

$$
\text{Log}(-x) = \ln(x) + (1 + 2n)\pi i
$$

So you can see that there are *no* values of the general Logarithm where it gives the same value for a positive and negative real value (since the negative value *always* requires odd integers and the positive value always requires even integers).

**Note**

You might wonder about that addition by $\ln(r)$ (remember $r$ is a *positive* real number).  Can't we write $r = e^{\ln(r)}$ with the more general $r = e^{\text{Log}(r)}$?  Well, of course you can, but then we simply get:

$$
\text{Log}\left(re^{\theta i}\right) = \ln(r) + 2\pi mi + \theta i +  2\pi n i
$$

But this ends up being $\text{Log}\left(re^{\theta i}\right) = \ln(r) + \theta i + 2\pi(m + n)i$...an addition of two integers is still just an integer though.

Comment: So then is $x^{x}$ equal $e^{x\ln{x}}$.

Comment: Not exactly, actually $x^x = e^{x\text{Log}(x)}$ where $\text{Log}$ is the more general complex logarithm (with base $e$).  Yes, it is true that for _positive real_ values of $x$, $x^x = e^{x\ln(x)}$ but it's _not_ true for negative real values where you _must_ use the [complex logarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_logarithm).